# CORS preflight channel did not succeed on DELETE method

Tags: angularjs, ajax, symfony

I've been stuck with this error for a while now, I am working on a Angular(1.6.1) app and when I call a delete method to the API (which I can access and modify) written in symfony 3. 
I had a preflight error previously with a post method, which I managed to solve by changing the request's headers.

Now here's my call to the API:

```
$http.delete('http://localhost:8000/utilisateurs/2').then(function(response) {
    $location.path('/register');
})
```

There is the CorsListener from the API:

```
  class CorsListener {
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
      $response = $event - > getResponse();
      $responseHeaders = $response - > headers;
      $responseHeaders - > set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept, X-Requested-With ');
      $responseHeaders - > set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      $responseHeaders - > set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
      $responseHeaders - > set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
      $event - > setResponse($response);
   }
 }
```

The .htaccess lines that could be helpful:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE,  OPTIONS"
```

The request is sent as an OPTION, and I can't change that behaviour according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

mod_headers is indeed activated in my apache conf, and I don't really know what to do now, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to fix it with NelmioCorsBundle, here's the config to help:

```
nelmio_cors:
paths:
   '^/':
       allow_credentials: true
       allow_origin: ['*']
       allow_headers: ['X-Requested-With', 'X-Prototype-Version', 'Cache-Control', 'Pragma', 'Origin', 'Content-Type', 'Accept']
       allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS']
       expose_headers: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']
       max_age: 3600
```